# How can I specify to what schema I need to apply my migration using Symfony doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When I use  `./bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` command my migrations apply to `public` schema. But in my Entities I set another schema :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MyEntityRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(schema="schemaname", name="entity")
 */
class MyEntity
```

How can I specify to what schema I need to apply my migration using Symfony doctrine?

Comment: Do you have migration file? select the schema in the migration file/command

Comment: @qdequippe It is an inconvenient way but despite this what about migrations table? Even if I select a schema in the migration file, `migration versions` appears in the `public` schema. My gut tells me that there should be a more elegant solution

Comment: Why not use `table_name: myschema.migration_version` in doctrine migration bundle configuration? ... check https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#configuration

Comment: @SilvioQ It is a pretty good answer. Write It please as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this configuration in your doctrine bundle configuration

```
doctrine_migrations:
    ...
    table_name: myschema.migration_version
    ...
```

Oficial documentation in  https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#configuration